# Vuejs 2.0+ how to use exteneral webcomponents in template of vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, web-component

I am fairly entrenched in the Vue ecosystem, but there is plenty more that I am learning. I recently came across a scenario that I do not know how to approach.

In short, there is a `rollup`-ed JavaScript file containing some [webcomponents](https://www.webcomponents.org/) that are not Vue. I would like to use these in a Nuxtjs spa. However, using these components in other vue components is proving a bit cumbersome.

I have tried a variety of approaches, e.g.

- Locally (in a dockerized environment), I can sandwich my nuxt / vue spa in between these external components by altering `src/app.html`, on the linked codesandbox however, they do not render correctly
- I have tried binding the components to a vue component template via `v-html`
- I have tried `Vue.config.ignoredElements`
- I have tried binding the components with the script tag that injects them

and various combinations thereof. I am providing a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-iu759?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to play with.

To see the correct behavior, please go to `/app.html` and copy lines 10-41 into a empty local html file and open it in your browser.

Any ideas how I can get these to play nice?

The only thing I found so far is this article:

- https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-integrate-web-components/

which is where I got the `Vue.config.ignoredElements` idea